# String comparison not working in databases, files... could the character set be an issue?

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, string

I recently encountered a strange problem with strings:

I had 2 tables:

```
| AgentCodes | CREATE TABLE `AgentCodes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `AgentName` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `AgentName` (`AgentName`),
) ENGINE=ndbcluster AUTO_INCREMENT=319 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

and

```
| AgentNumbers | CREATE TABLE `AgentNumbers` (
  `AgentName` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `TelephoneNumber` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `AgentName` (`AgentName`),
  KEY `TelephoneNumber` (`TelephoneNumber`),
) ENGINE=ndbcluster AUTO_INCREMENT=62 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

`LIKE` didn't work on AgentCodes.AgentName table, I guessed it was because AgentName had `unicode` charset, so I changed charset on that field to `Latin1`.

Now the problem is AgentNumbers table is used as realtime table for AsteriskPBX queue
Basically, I get the name of the Agent and put caller in that queue.

For example I get the name JohnDoe, the conf file looks like this:

```
[JohnDoe]
musicclass = temp
timeout = 35
member => SIP/...
```

And I get an error saying *no such queue*. I knew what the problem was so I copied the name from the database to that conf file and it worked.

My question is what could cause that problem, to see 2 strings one in file and other in database, copy/paste them in a third file (where they still *look* identical) and they are not recognized as being the same?

I guess it has something to do with Encoding/Charset, but I would like to hear why :)

Comment: What is the actual question and what solution do you expect?

Comment: AgentCodes.AgentName LIKE '<what>'???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget MySQL LIKE does character wise comparison, not string comparisons. So things like trailing spaces matter. And we don't have the actual SQL, for example is it a literal or variable you are comparing to.

Also, why have AgentName in 2 different tables? This doesn't look normalised, and of course you are finding out now why normalisation matters.

Comment: Thanks for replay. There were and still are no spaces. I copy name from both tables to file and still don\t see the difference between them, yet they can't match. It's not normalised at all, that is because of slopy work, and less experiance on it :)